# navigator.clipboard refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make this code not refresh every time the copy_button is pressed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<button id='copy_button'>Copy Link</button>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
copy_set = "copy me!";
document.getElementById("copy_button").addEventListener("click", event => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copy_set);
});
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? I don't see any behavior of the sort happening.

Answer (score 2):

When a button is clicked, the page is refreshed as default behavior. In order to prevent the page from refreshing, you would need to add the `preventDefault()` method. Your JavaSacript code should look like this:

```
copy_set = "copy me!";
document.getElementById("copy_button").addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copy_set);
});
```